# I am a revert and would like to know if my Nikkah is valid

Tags: nikah

Salam! I am a revert and Me and my partner had an online Nikkah in August 2023 with an Imam and 2 witnesses. All cameras were turned off. We received a certificate. Following the Hanafi rulings, a woman is not required to have a Wali so I did not have anyone. Both of our families are not aware of this Nikkah as my partner wanted to keep it a secret. Nobody from my family knows that I am Muslim as my parents are very against the religion. I am constantly doubting myself and feel that I have made a mistake. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Requirement for Valid Nikah

1. Permission of Wali of Bride
2. Permission of the girl who is to be married
3. Mahr (Dowry given by husband to wife which is agreed between them or their elders]
4. 2 male adult sane witnesses (if female sane adult are witnesses than 2 females = 1 male ie 4 female witnesses]
5. Waleema (Wedding feast] given by husband (Optional & depend on the capacity of husband]

It is consensus among Scholars and Imams that women cannot marry without the permission of Wali. Though Hanafi Fiqh has a different opinion on the matter.

Since you are a revert and if your both maternal and paternal side's male elders are **not Muslim** then they **Cannot be your Wali**.

When there is no male elder who cannot act as Wali for a woman then it is Muslim Ruler who is Wali and he may appoint someone for the girl. In case of non-muslim countries, a Masjid's Imam can act as Wali for the girl.

I advise you to redo nikah as it is safer. Ask and request any Imam of the nearby mosque to act your Wali.

Also, I advise that your husband should announce the marriage to his own parents and family if they are Muslims. Many times rights are not preserved and even man refuses to recognize the woman as his wife when the relationship is exposed especially cases of Gulf countries citizen living in foreign countries as men are not allowed to marry any foreign women without prior permission from govt, unlike other countries which do not bother over such things.

May Allah Protect you and guide you.